# Firebase cloud function finishes with status code 304

Tags: angular, firebase, promise, google-cloud-firestore

I'm having trouble finding out why the following function finished with a status code of 304 rather then sending the 200 response. The documents update as required, but I want to get the correct status code.

```
const firestoreInstance = admin.firestore();

export async function onTwitchGiveawayPostback(req, res) {
    const reward = 1;

    const userName = await utils.getParameterByName('name', req.originalUrl);

    if (!userName) { throw new Error('User Display Name is not set on REQLoot :('); }

    const displayNameDocPath = firestoreInstance.collection('displayNames').doc(userName);

    return displayNameDocPath.get().then(snapshot => snapshot.data()).then(displayNameDocDetails => {
        if (!displayNameDocDetails) {
            res.status(200).send('User Display Name: ' + userName + ' is not set on REQLoot :(');
            return Promise.resolve('Ok');
        } else {
            const uid = displayNameDocDetails.uid;

            const staminaEntryDoc   = firestoreInstance.collection(utils.API_URLS.userStaminaBalanceSheet + '/' + uid + '/entries').doc();
            const userDocPath       = firestoreInstance.collection('users').doc(uid);

            const promises = [];
            promises.push(
                userDocPath.get(),
            );

            return Promise.all(promises).then((snapshots) => {
                return Promise.all(snapshots.map((doc) => {
                    return doc.data();
                })).then(data => {
                    const userDocDetails = data[0];

                    const serverTimestamp = admin.firestore.Timestamp.now();

                    const batch = firestoreInstance.batch();

                    const staminaBalanceSheetDescription = 'winner';
                    const staminaPrev = userDocDetails.stamina;
                    const staminaNew = staminaPrev + reward;

                    batch.update(userDocPath, {
                        stamina: staminaNew,
                        updatedAt: serverTimestamp,
                    });

                    // Update the User's stamina balance sheet
                    batch.set(staminaEntryDoc, {
                        description: staminaBalanceSheetDescription,
                        stamina: {
                            previous: staminaPrev,
                            new: staminaNew,
                        },
                        staminaAmount: reward,
                        updatedAt: serverTimestamp,
                    });

                    return batch.commit();
                })
                .then(() => {
                    res.status(200).send(userName + ' won some stamina!');
                })
                .catch((err) => {
                    console.error(err)
                    return err;
                });
            })
        }
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
}
```

Other posts have mentioned that the function always needs to return a Promise, but I think I've added them where necessary. What am I missing that is preventing a normal 200 response?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was CORS.

The function was executing and updating firestore, but returning a 304 status code and not sending the string payload. Updating the function with the following line:

`res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');`

Allowed for a 200 status code and proper string being sent on completion.